# Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_OWNER_NOT_ROOT)

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

when I try to start a `vm` in `Virtualbox`, I get the error in the title message.

I have already checked `/usr/lib/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0` and the permissions are

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 785K Sep 21  2013 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0
```

What other things will cause this error, and what other things can I try?

Comment: What's the OS you're running VB on? Also what user are you trying to run VB as?

Comment: @sim, Host OS = `Ubuntu 13.10`. Guest OS = Not yet installed. I am trying to run VB as myself, a user with `sudo` privileges who is not root.

Comment: How did you install VB? I run it as a non-root user w/o sudo as well.

Comment: I downloaded from Oracle's website, and used `sudo dpkg -i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this thread titled: [VERR_SUPLIB_OWNER_NOT_ROOT - solved](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=39179) which describes several possible reasons why you'd get this message. Most of them stem from the permissions not being set properly.

In addition to making sure the permissions are correct for the file you mentioned you'll want to make sure that the permissions for the directories that its inside are also right. Here's what my directory structure looks like:

```
$ ls -ld /usr /usr/lib64 /usr/lib64/virtualbox /usr/lib64/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0
drwxr-xr-x.  14 root root    4096 Dec 10 14:29 /usr
drwxr-xr-x. 238 root root  147456 Apr  4 03:16 /usr/lib64
drwxr-xr-x.   5 root root    4096 Apr  4 03:16 /usr/lib64/virtualbox
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root 1277952 Dec 26 13:31 /usr/lib64/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0
```

I'd started with that. Also notice that the directories have a little trailing dot on the permissions attributes.You might need to add a context to the file and/or directories as well.

If that's the case I'd expect to see some error messages regarding this in either SELinux or AppArmor.

#### contexts

You can check what the contexts which are being applied to a directory by using the `-Z` switch to `ls`.

```
$ ls -ldZ /usr /usr/lib64 /usr/lib64/virtualbox /usr/lib64/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       /usr
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       /usr/lib64
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       /usr/lib64/virtualbox
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0       /usr/lib64/virtualbox/VMMR0.r0
```

So in my case the contexts are `system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0`.

#### References

- [Getting VERR_SUPLIB_OWNER_NOT_ROOT error after upgrading to 4.0.0, Linux host](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7889)

Comment: @sim, I noticed the little `.` which I do not have. How do I add a context?

Comment: @merlin2011 - see updates. Also what version of VB?

Comment: @sim, I rebooted and checked the permissions on each of those directories again. For some reason, even though I installed the 64-bit version of VirtualBox, it was still in `/usr/lib` and not `/usr/lib64`. It turns out `/usr/lib` was owned by user with ID `501` although I cannot imagine how that happened.

Comment: @merlin2011- glad this solved it.It probably happened when you did the installation. All the research I did seem to lead to this situations arising when installation was done as a user with elevated privs. BTW you can upvote in addition to accepting 8-)